# What is the significance of Ukrainian and Belarusian flags on anti-Zeman protest rally in Prague?

Tags: ukraine, flag, czech-republic, belarus

On 30 April 2021, thousands of Czechs [have rallied](https://www.rferl.org/a/czechs-rally-against-president-zeman-over-russia-views/31230366.html) in Prague against President Milos Zeman, calling for his removal from office and condemning what opponents say are his pro-Russia views.

[image: Ukrainian and Belarusian flags on rally in Prague]
<sub>[Photo by AFP](https://www.kyivpost.com/eastern-europe/rfe-rl-thousands-rally-against-czech-president-over-russia-stance.html)</sub>

Reading the news about the event, I noticed that the protesters held three large flags: of the European Union, of Ukraine, and of Belarus.  I don't follow the logical link between the protest and the flags. I'm aware about [the recent events](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-56796324) in Czech Republic and how it might be related to Ukraine, but again, that does not explain the linkage to the flag of Belarus.

Has any of the protesters explained the significance of Ukrainian and Belarusian flags on the rally?

Comment: Ukrainians and Belarussian expats or advocates wanting publicity for their cause, specially in the middle of a probably sympathetic public?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer "properly" unless someone carrying the flags makes a statement. But to me the most likely reason is expression of solidarity with the Ukranians and Belorussians (considering recent events) as a proxy for anti-Russian (or better say, anti-Russian-Federation) sentiment - which is largely the point of the protest.